# How to dynamically assign value in elasticsearch query?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have Parent-Child mapping. Can I dynamically assign value in elasticsearch's query? I want `max_children` and `min_children` to be evaluated per parent. I've tried something like this, but it is not working:

```
"min_children": {
  "script": "doc['boxes_count'].value"
}, 
"max_children": {
  "script": "doc['boxes_count'].value"
}
```

Current query looks like that, and is actually working

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/star_cars_development_car_washes/_search?pretty' -d '
{
  "query": {
    "has_child" : {
      "type" : "reservation",
      "min_children": 10, 
      "max_children": 10, 
      "query": {
        "filtered": {
          "filter": {
            "bool": {
              "must": [
                {
                  "range": {
                    "date": {"lte": "2015-07-21T03:36:00.000+03:00"}
                  }
                },
                {
                  "range": {
                    "ends_at": {"gte": "2015-07-21T03:36:00.000+03:00"}
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

Comment: How do you want them evaluated? What is 'boxes_count'?

Comment: Just some parent's field with numeric value. Every parent has its own that differs from others. So I want to assign max_children/min_children value to parent's boxes_count via elasticsearch dsl. The task is find all parents that have as many filtered children as boxes_count is.